# How to feed IQueryable Data to Telerik Grid in Domain Driven Development DDD

Tags: entity-framework, data-binding, telerik, domain-driven-design

I want to do paging data in database side for telerik grid but Mapping data between layers prevent it in DDD architecture.

How can I do it?

Explanation:

I have a Domain Model (`News`) in Project.Domain.cproj and a Data Model (`NewsDataModel`) in Project.Data.cproj.

In ASP.Net MVC I have a Telerik Grid and need a method on Controller to feed data to it.

```
public ActionResult GridList()
{
    return Json(new GridModel(_newsService.GetAll()));
}
```

and `_newsService.GetAll()` is as follow :

```
public IQueryable<News> GetAll()
{
    return _newsRepository.GetAll().AsEnumerable().Select(ToDomainModel).AsQueryable();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest that you review [this](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/iqueryable-for-paging-filtering.aspx) thread on Telerik Forum regarding this.

Comment: It be great if you included the details from the thread, especially since the link is broken.